# Why can't I install apps on Windows 8 using specific dial-up modem connections?

Tags: windows-8, internet-connection, windows-8.1, windows-store

This problem has persisted since I first tried out Windows 8 Consumer Preview, and also affects Windows 8, Windows 8.1 Preview, and Windows 8.1. Specifically, the problem occurs when I try to **install apps** from the Windows Store on a **Globe Tattoo Broadband** or **Smart Bro** dial-up connection (two common ways of connecting to the internet in the **Philippines**).
I can confirm that this isn't a problem with my copy of Windows or my Microsoft account because I was able to install any app on other connections like public WiFi. This problem has persisted on three different dongles and two different computers.
So why can't I install apps on those two specific types of connections?

Comment: What exactly happens when you try?

Comment: ^The download either stops before completion or doesn't start at all. The error code returned is 0x8020002e

Comment: Interesting. 0x8020002e is a DATA_BUS_ERROR error, and points to faulty hardware.  If you've tried different modem dongles and different computers, then I'd suspect the drivers for the dongles need to be updated for 8.1 (by the manufacturer of the dongle). Have you checked with them for an updated driver?

Comment: Yes, but--surprise, surprise--there have been no response to my emails to their customer support, and I don't even want to try calling them, because the last time I tried that it was _unpleasant_. But if it's a problem with the hardware, why can I still browse the internet fine and download from other sites? Only the Windows Store doesn't work.

Comment: Just uninstall your modem and reinstall it.
it will definately help.